# dplyr arrange removes additional class information of all variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the problem, with additional class information of variables in a data frame. This should serve as meta information to be used in later operations with mutate_if, summarise_if....

I use this to make sure that no variable is forgotten in calculations, regardless of the name. But also to be able to quickly format with DT.

This works pretty fine. The information will be preserved in all operations and will also be passed to new calculated variables. But after an **arrange()**, this **information is lost** for all variables.
Please see the example.

**Is it possible to keep the information?**

**Do I assign the class information incorrectly?**

**Should one avoid such meta information?**

```
as.ratio <- function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x))
    class(x) <- append(class(x), "ratio")
  else
    warning("value is not numeric!")
  return(x)
}

is.ratio <- function(x){
  "ratio" %in% class(x)
}

df <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = runif(a,0,3), c = runif(a,0,2), d = runif(a,0,3), l = LETTERS[sample(1:length(LETTERS), length(a), replace = T)])
df <- df %>% mutate(
  ab = as.ratio(a/b),
  ac = as.ratio(a/c),
  ad = as.ratio(a/d)
)

df %>% lapply(function(col){
  return(class(col))
})


$a
[1] "integer"

$b
[1] "numeric"

$c
[1] "numeric"

$d
[1] "numeric"

$l
[1] "character"

$ab
[1] "numeric" "ratio"  

$ac
[1] "numeric" "ratio"  

$ad
[1] "numeric" "ratio"
```

So its all fine, now execute examle mutate_if & mutate

```
result1 <- df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.ratio, ~ . * 0.2) %>% 
  mutate(new_ratio = ab * ac)
result1 %>% lapply(function(col){
  return(class(col))
})

$a
[1] "integer"

$b
[1] "numeric"

$c
[1] "numeric"

$d
[1] "numeric"

$l
[1] "character"

$ab
[1] "numeric" "ratio"  

$ac
[1] "numeric" "ratio"  

$ad
[1] "numeric" "ratio"  

$new_ratio
[1] "numeric" "ratio"
```

Great the result I expected. But now the problem that occurs after the execution of: arrange

```
result2 <- df %>% 
  arrange(l) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.ratio, ~ . * 0.2) %>% 
  mutate(new_ratio = ab * ac)

result2 %>% lapply(function(col){
  return(class(col))
})

$a
[1] "integer"

$b
[1] "numeric"

$c
[1] "numeric"

$d
[1] "numeric"

$l
[1] "character"

$ab
[1] "numeric"

$ac
[1] "numeric"

$ad
[1] "numeric"

$new_ratio
[1] "numeric"
```

*'ratio'* information is lost, so mutate_if does nothing and new_ration doesn't get the *'ratio'* class information.

Thanks for your advises.

Comment: Your code works fine with me. I guess you have multiple packages loaded in the current environment which have `arrange` function. If this is the case you have to assign the preference to dplyr. Use `dplyr::arrange(l)`

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved this way and this works pretty fine.

I used the posibility of define own attributes with attr. This information will keep thru all oparations, even sum, cumsum, mean......

```
as.type <- function(obj, type){
  base::attr(obj, "type") <- base::append(base::attr(obj, "type"), type)
  return(obj)
} 

is.type <- function(obj, type){
  type %in% base::attr(obj, "type")
} 

as.ratio <- function(obj){
  as.type(obj, "ratio")
}

is.ratio <- function(obj){
  is.type(obj, "ratio")
}

as.currency <- function(obj){
  as.type(obj, "currency")
}

is.currency <- function(obj){
  is.type(obj, "currency")
}
```